# How can I generate an M3U playlist (http URL format) from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, music, mp3, playlists

I'd like to generate a M3U playlist for a directory containing mp3 files on my server from the terminal. Since I'd like to ensure that every player will be able to stream those files I'd like to prefix each file entry with the absolute URL to that directory, like this:

```
http://server.com/dir/file1.mp3
http://server.com/dir/file2.mp3
...
```

So unfortunately simply doing `ls -1 *.mp3 > play.m3u` isn't enough. Is there a one-liner to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the following one-liner should work:

`for f in *.mp3; do echo "http://..../$f" >> play.m3u; done`

Answer (score 10):

This is @chronitis answer with some improvements :

- stores the file name on the variable $playlist for later use
- will delete the file if exists previously
- writes the full path of the file  on the playlist

The command

```
playlist='play.m3u' ; if [ -f $playlist ]; then rm $playlist ; fi ; for f in *.mp3; do echo "$(pwd)/$f" >> "$playlist"; done
```

To play it with mplayer on the command line also

```
mplayer -playlist play.m3u
```

Comment: I don't know why somebody downvoted this answer. This is the only solution that seems to work right out of the box and should be accepted or at least promoted. Thank you very much!

Comment: what if i want to add multiple file formats into this command?

Answer (score 4):

You originally asked to create each entry as a web URL formatted line.  In addition to replacing the local path with http://..., you'll also need to replace spaces with '%20'.  So, long line, but here you go:

```
find /path/to/mp3s/ -name "*.mp3" | sed 's/ /%20/g' | sed 's|/path/to/mp3s/|http://www.server.com/serverpath/|g' > playlist.m3u
```

Comment: good idea! using a plus (+) sign instead would result in a more readable URL though

Answer (score 2):

This bash script can do the job:

```
rawurlencode() {
  local string="${1}"
  local strlen=${#string}
  local encoded=""
  local pos c o

  for (( pos=0 ; pos<strlen ; pos++ )); do
     c=${string:$pos:1}
     case "$c" in
        [-_.~a-zA-Z0-9] ) o="${c}" ;;
        * )               printf -v o '%%%02x' "'$c"
     esac
     encoded+="${o}"
  done
  echo "${encoded}"
}

rm -rf p.m3u
for f in *.mkv; do echo "#EXTINF:-1,SR:$f
  http://10.0.0.144/tvtmp/"$(rawurlencode $f) >> p.m3u; 
done
sed -i '1s/^/#EXTM3U\n/' p.m3u
rm -rf l.m3u
for f in *.mkv; do echo "#EXTINF:-1,SR:$f
  http://127.0.0.1/tvtmp/$f" >> l.m3u; 
done
sed -i '1s/^/#EXTM3U\n/' l.m3u
```

A little more developed version. The URL is encoded in proper `.m3u` style.

Answer (score 0):

### Like this post on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1428968), I try [`mkpl`](https://github.com/MatteoGuadrini/mkpl) with some examples proposed by creator:

1. Create a playlist for one music album:

   ```bash
   cd myalbum
   mkpl myalbum.m3u
   ```
2. Create a playlist of a film saga

   ```bash
   mkpl -d HarryPotter -f mkv HP_saga.m3u
   ```
3. Create a shuffled playlist with my music collection

   ```bash
   mkpl -d "my_mp3_collection" "my_mp4_collection" -rs "my music.m3u"
   ```
4. Create a shuffled playlist with my music collection and exclude dirs

   ```bash
   mkpl -d "my_mp3_collection" "my_mp4_collection" -r -s -e "my_mp3_collection/metallica" "my_mp3_collection/dk" "my music.m3u"
   ```
5. Create a TV series playlist with max 15 tracks

   ```bash
   mkpl -d "my_series/GOT" -m 15 "got_first_15.m3u"
   ```
6. Add into *my music* playlist new songs and don't add same file

   ```bash
   mkpl -d "new_collection" -rsu "my music.m3u" -a
   ```
7. Create playlist with music and video files if files is greater then 10MB

   ```bash
   mkpl -d "my_files" -r -z 10485760 "multimedia.m3u"
   ```
8. Create playlist with only number one and two tracks wit regular expression

   ```bash
   mkpl -d "my_mp3_collection" -r -p "^[12]|[012]{2}" "my music.m3u"
   ```
9. Create a playlist for one music album and set the title:

   ```bash
   cd myalbum
   mkpl myalbum.m3u -t "My Album"
   ```
10. Create a playlist and add *UTF-8* encoding

    ```bash
    mkpl -d "new_collection" -r "my music.m3u" -g "UTF-8"
    ```
11. Create a playlist and set image

    ```bash
    mkpl -d "new_collection" -r "my music.m3u" -I "new_collection/playlist_cover.jpg"
    ```
12. Create a playlist and add remote file links

    ```bash
    mkpl -d "new_collection" -r "my music.m3u" -l http://192.168.1.123/mp3/song1.mp3, http://192.168.1.123/mp3/song2.mp4
    ```
13. Create a playlist and set Windows backslash () folder separator (for Windows OS)

    ```bash
    mkpl -d "new_collection" -r "my music.m3u" -w
    ```