# How to automatically create `.m3u` (or other playlist file) for multiple directories supporting multiple file formats?

Tags: command-line, scripts, nautilus, video, rhythmbox

I want to create a `.m3u` (playlist) file for every folder that's inside a directory, automatically and save it inside that particular folder with the name of that particular folder?

**How to Create an .m3u file with command?**

```
 playlist='play.m3u' ; if [ -f $playlist ]; then rm $playlist ; fi ; for f in *.mp3|; do echo "$(pwd)/$f" >> "$playlist"; done
```

This command does it for ".mp3" files, for a single directory

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/437082/665251)

**Multiple File formats**

I want the above command to work on any Audio/Video formats. extensions like `.m4a`  `.flac`  `.mp4` `.mkbv` so that it can be used for Video playlists as well

**Multiple Directories**

[image: Multiple directories]

if I apply the script on the parent folder of these folders, each one of these folders should get their own `.m3u` file

**Nautilus Script**

if possible a Nautilus Script that could do all this with a right click would be amazing, i'm ready to give more outputs or anything else required

**Advantages**

1. Good File Management
2. it'll automatically add the playlist with the name of the album in Rythmbox (or other music players)
3. Once it's done their is no need to play files from going folder to folder

Answer (score 1):

```
find -type f -iname "*.mp3" -or -iname "*.flac" -or -iname "*.m4a" > playlist.m3u
```

Another idea is you could use a bash loop and check for the mime type using the `file` command:

```
echo "" > playlist.m3u

for path in $(find -type f) do;
   if [ file --mime-type "$path" | egrep '(audio|video)' ]; then
      echo "$path" >> playlist.m3u
   fi
done
```

Answer (score -1):

Doing a research in this field, I found this [Bash script to create .m3u playlist files for all mp3s in subdirectories](https://gist.github.com/scarlson/944860) created by [scarlson](https://gist.github.com/scarlson).

This meets your most essential requirements: multiple file formats and multiple directories.